# CLIP command does not function properly

Tags: batch-file, copy, clipboard

I have a batch script that runs on startup to copy both of mails so that I can paste anywhere I like with Ditto(basically a clipboard history program).
But with my current script I have to wait for 2 seconds until its finished.
Without the timeout it does not work, it only copies the second mail
When I use ping instead of timeout it, too, copies only the second mail.

Since the duration of the batch is 2 seconds I often interfere with it and it takes up much more time than it should.

Can you help me?

I always run the batch file.

```
@echo off
timeout 1
ECHO | SET /P=sampleMailOne@gmail.com| CLIP
timeout 1
ECHO | SET /P=sampleMailTwo@gmail.com| CLIP
```

Comment: I suspect it isn't `clip` that "does not function properly", but `Ditto`, which has to grab contents from the Windows Clipboard (probably by periodically checking the Windows Clipboard for changes)

Comment: Do remember that `clip` overwrites the text content of the clipboard. If `Ditto` is unable to capture the clipboard within the 1 second delay of the two clip commands,  then the `sampleMailOne@gmail.com` will not be captured. The second email address is captured because there is enough time for Ditto to capture the clipboard. Consider increasing number of checks, or lengthen the `timeout` between the two clips.